# Ektron UrlAliasing module in web.config

Tags: web-config, ektron

Can anyone explain the following module entry in the web.config of an Ektron site?

```
 <add name="EkUrlAliasModule" type="UrlAliasingModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ektron has a [URL Aliasing module](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v85/webhelp/Navigating/URLs/URL_aliasing_intro.htm) that allows business users int the workarea to define user/SEO-friendly URLS for pages in the CMS.

That entry in the web.config is what the asp.net application uses to refer to that module.